ProgISP giving an error "Flash is not empty"
I was trying to program an AVR microcontroller using ProgISP 1.72 but it gave me a "Flasher is not empty" error, I don't know what it means nor how to fix it, it was working fine before hand.
I tried reverting the last change which was a change in jumper cables, also tried a different hex file.

Did you erase the flash first?  Most programmers do erasure and programming as separate steps.  You can only flash an erased chip.

Thanks that works but now it gives me a new error; "Flash verify error: at xh",
x changes between tries ranging from 0 to 61,
and I still don't know why I needed to manually erase the chip if I am leaving the option to do so automatically on.

Please tell us EXACTLY the steps you are using to program this chip.  I suspect you're simply doing it wrong.

I use CodeVision 3.14 to write a simple code,
then I built it and use progISP to load the hex file into the micro controller (atMega32a)
in progisp the settings I leave on are (verify signature, chip erase, blank check, program flash, verify flash), and I use the auto key to program the micro controller without manually erasing the micro controller beforehand.
I use an external crystal so I changed the fuses, the first time I worked on it, which was a couple of weeks ago.

since then I tried a couple of things like erasing the MC manually and writing the flash which worked for a couple of times then stopped working again, the I tried to reset the fuses, such that the MC uses its internal frequency, which made progISP write the hex file fine for now. I will try to change the crystal and capacitors with new ones and see if it will work with the external frequency or not.
